# Private var inside Javascript literal object

Tags: javascript, private, var, object-literal

How can I declare a private var inside a literal object? Becasuse I've this code:

```
var foo = {

    self: null,

    init: function() {
        self = this;
        self.doStuff();
    },

    doStuff: function() {
        //stuff here
    }

}
```

This works perfectly, but if I have some objects, the var "self" it will override.. apparently it's a global var.. and I cannot use the restricted word "var" inside this object..

How can I solve this, or make an NameSpace for each object?

Thanks!

Comment: Why `self = this; self.doStuff()` instead of `this.doStuff()`?

Comment: -1 Post what you're *actually trying to do* in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add private variable to this Javascript object literal snippet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396294/how-to-add-private-variable-to-this-javascript-object-literal-snippet)

Comment: @delnan You would need to do this if you were using the Google Closure Compiler where assigning stuff to "this" is dangerous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a function scope to hide the variable:

```
var foo = (function() {
  var self = null
  return {
    init: ...,
    doStuff: ...
  };
})();
```

Though it is not clear what `self` is supposed to do here, and how `foo` is used.

Comment: This prevents you from reusing the object literal for more instances. You've effectively created a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this`:

```
init: function() {
  this.self = this;
  this.self.doStuff();
},
```

*edit* However, it's still a property of the "foo" object, and it's not super-clear where you're getting instances of "foo" from.  In other words, the way your code is written, there's only one object.

Alternatively, you could create your object with a closure:

```
var foo = function() {
    var self = null;

    return {
      init: function() {
        self = this;
        self.doStuff();
      },

      doStuff: function() {
        //stuff here
      }
    };
}();
```

Comment: Not a global variable, per se, but it is accessible from the global scope.

Comment: Ah, well sort-of.  I see what you mean. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The problem is when I've inside a method like init() a jQuery function.. $(selector).click(function(){ self.objectMethod()  }) If I haven't a reference to my object, it's impossible  call to the objet methods..

Comment: @mauriblint: Why on earth don't you just include all relevant information in the question?! You have some in the question, some here, and we're still missing some parts, like the relationship between the object and the element clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You are not even using the property that you have created. Instead you create another global variable with the same name. Use the `this` keyword to access properties:

```
var foo = {

  self: null,

  init: function() {
    this.self = this;
    this.self.doStuff();
  },

  doStuff: function() {
    //stuff here
  }

}
```

(Although saving `this` in a property is truly pointless...)

If you want a local variable in the object, create a closure for it:

```
var foo = (function(){

  var self = null;

  return {

    init: function() {
      self = this;
      self.doStuff();
    },

    doStuff: function() {
      //stuff here
    }
  };

}());
```

Comment: The problem is when I've inside a method like init() a jQuery function.. $(selector).click(function(){ self.objectMethod() }) If I haven't a reference to my object, it's impossible call to the objet methods.. Have I made myself clear? Thanks!

Comment: @mauriblint: That's because you are not *inside* the `init` method when the event happens. Use a closure as I showed above.