# Do I need to define 'self', 'element' etc. at the start of every function within a JQuery Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-widget-factory, jquery-ui-widget

I create JQuery Widgets something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
        $.widget("cb.bacon", {
            _create: function() {
                var self = this,
                    o = self.options,
                    el = self.element;

                 // Some code

            },

            _bacon: function() {
                var self = this,
                    o = self.options,
                    el = self.element;

                 // Some code
            },

            _smokey: function() {
                var self = this,
                    o = self.options,
                    el = self.element;

                 // Some code
            } 
        });
    })(jQuery);                 
</script>
```

I invariably end up having to declare `self`, `options`, `element` in each function that I create.

Is there some fundimental understanding that I'm missing or do I really have to do that all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do that at all, that is only to make it easier to access those inside the function.

The `self` variable is useful when you are using a callback in a jQuery function, where `this` would be set to the element that you are acting upon. For example:

```
$('.bacon').each(function(){ $(this).css('background', self.getBackground()); });
```

The variables `o` and `el` just makes for less typing. If you have the varaible `self`, or the reference `this` unchanged, you can access the `options` and `element` properties from the object directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare these things each time since you are using an object literal.   You could wrap the object literal as a function call and achieve what you want that way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeTheBacon() {
    var self = this;
    var o = self.options;
    var el = self.element;

    self._create = function() {...};
    self._bacon = function() {...};
    self._smokey = function() {...};
    return self;
}

(function ($) {
    $.widget("cb.bacon", makeTheBacon());
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

There is also a questions that touches on this also by using functions in the object literal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396294/how-to-add-private-variable-to-this-javascript-object-literal-snippet), but that seemed overly verbose considering your original question.