# Private Member To Object Containing Function

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I have an object containing a function and want to add to it a private member.
How can I do that?

```
function function1 () {
    var function2 = function () {
        console.log("This is an actual function.");
    }

    function2.publicMember = 5;
    function2.privateMember = 7; 

    return function2;
}
```

I want privatMember to be inaccessible to the user of function1.
I found this question but I can't quite translate it to my situation because my object is a function:

[How to add private variable to this Javascript object literal snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396294/how-to-add-private-variable-to-this-javascript-object-literal-snippet)

thanks!

Comment: You _can_ define it with `var privateMember;` which would make it accessible only in the closure (and not a part of function2 outside this context) but seriously - there is a simpler solution. Just name it `_privateMember` and don't change it from the outside. You're an adult and you're perfectly capable of this :)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really have private object properties at this point. And it would be unusual to add properties to functions, except in some very specific cases. If you make `privateMember` a variable decalred as `var privateMember = 7`, then your `function2` will have access to it, and it will be otherwise inaccessible outside `function1`

Comment: Just to be clear, adding a '_' to the property name is convention for privacy but doesn't actually change behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it into one more function to create new scope (i.e. using [iife](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)):

```
function function1 () {
     var function2 = (function(){
       var privateMember = 7; 
       return function () {
          privateMember ++; // do something with really private member
          console.log("This is an actual function.");
       }
    })();

    function2.publicMember = 5;

    return function2;
}
```

Comment: You still won't be able to access publicMember within function2 itself though.

Comment: @johnnycardy - good point, but sometimes it is not necessary (i.e. in jQuery `$.each()` - `$` function don't really care of presence of `each`/don't need to access `each`)

Answer (score 1):

Declare the vars inside the function that needs access to them:

```
function function1 () {
    var publicMember = 5;
    var function2 = function () {
        var privateMember = 7;
        console.log("This is an actual function.");
    }

    return function2;
}
```

So function2 can see the vars inside its own closure (privateMember) and any parent scope.

Comment: I think this way privateMember's value won't live beyond the run of function2, am I right? I need to be able to access it from public functions I added onto function2 object.

Comment: Adding functions (or other properties) on to a function object is a really weird thing to do. Maybe it would be easier to create a prototype and instantiate that?