# Is there a reason for using a constructor for building one-time objects?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

On the site TodoMVC, there is a demo of an one-page app, coded with Vanilla JS.

[Todos app - Vanilla JavaScript Example](http://todomvc.com/vanilla-examples/vanillajs/)

They are using constructors to build the app, like this:

```
function Model() {
    ...;
}

function View() {
    ...;
}

function MyApp() {
    this.model = new Model();
    this.view = new View();
}

var todo = new MyApp();
```

For a one-page app (so the objects todo, todo.model and todo.view are unique), is there a good reason to use constructors like above, or is it more adapted to just build these objects without constructors :

```
var todo = {};
todo.model = {};
todo.view = {};
```

And, in the case of this (simplest) pattern is better, why the authors of TodoMVC are using constructors?

Comment: This talk [GDC 2012 from console to chrome](http://youtu.be/XAqIpGU8ZZk) from lilli thompson has recommendations how to enable v8 to optimize your javascript. If i remember correctly she gave a reason why to use constructors. More [links about optimizing javascript](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/03/Optimizing-JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

```
  var todo = {};
```

is an object of no particular type that will have to be populated by hand, while

```
  var todo = new MyApp();
```

is an object of class MyApp.

In case you will want to extend your application makes sense to have a concrete type object which can then take advantage of all OOP functionalities (e.g. inheritance).

I'm not a JS expert though.

Comment: +1 from me: If i remember this has something to do for v8 being able to optimize better. In the video [GDC 2012: from console to chrome](http://youtu.be/XAqIpGU8ZZk) Lilli Thompson recommended to not add properties to an object later because this way v8 can make less optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

They implemented a small MVC (Model/View/Controller) framework in pure JavaScript. Even though the current app `Todo` uses only one model, one controller and one view, those components are meant to be used multiple times, for larger applications.

You have to distinguish between the framework code (controller.js, model.js, view.js, template.js) and the actual application code (app.js). The first files are supposed to be reused for different applications, while the last one seems to be application specific.

Answer (score 0):

After having deepened my research, I think a possible answer is that you can't have private variables and méthods in a simple literal object.

An excerpt of [the answer by Pete Kirkham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396294/how-to-add-private-variable-to-this-javascript-object-literal-snippet/1396318#1396318) at the question :

> *How to add private variable to this Javascript object literal snippet?*
>
> It rather depends what you want to do with the object - the normal
> technique for 'private' members means they are accessible only by
> member functions, and requires that you use a constructor to create
> the object. The literal syntax is used for data structures or light
> weight objects with public data and functions.

Privacy is an essential element of modern design patterns in Javascript, and we can't have privacy without using a function.

Comment: Still, we can have privacy without using functions as *constructors*.